# How to avoid route when clicked on hash tag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have link in tiny carousel in the page,and i am using AngularJS route concept to build Single Page App. tiny carousel uses anchor tag as buttons to slide the images.

```
                  <div class="carousel-controls-mini">
                      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&#60;</a>
                      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&#62;</a>
                  </div>
```

but when i click the next button the page is redirecting to default page i.e /home.

script.js

```
            when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
            }).

            when('/unlimited', {
                templateUrl: 'license-unlimited.html',
            }).

            when('/my-licenses', {
                templateUrl: 'my-licenses.html',
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
```

How can i resolve this issue? need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-target` instead.

Change

```
<div class="carousel-controls-mini">
         <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&#60;</a>
         <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&#62;</a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="carousel-controls-mini">
       <a href="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&#60;</a>
       <a href="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&#62;</a>
</div>
```